# alternatives to pickle when saving a sklearn model pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a scikit-learn pipeline (min-max scaling -> poly(degree=2) -> lasso model).  I want to be able to save and use this model without pickling primarily because of compatiblity between versions of sklearn and to some degree, unease over pickle's security flaws.

If I was just using lasso, I could simply save and re-use the model's coefficients but not quite sure how to easily save/re-use the first parts of the models pipeline.

I could write code to re-product the first two steps but ideally there is an easier way to go about it.  Can anyone suggest alternative ways to save and re-use full sklearn pipelines?  Any good examples?

Comment: Scikit learn recommends joblib, which is based internally on pickle but handles scikit classes well.

Comment: Or else you can try PMML. See the https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn

Comment: yeah, joblib == pickle.  jpmml-sklearn looks interesting though